# Google cloud storage bad encoding of UTF-8 files

Tags: character-encoding, http-headers, google-cloud-storage

I have a `.txt` file encoded in UTF-8 in google cloud storage.
When I visit the public URL of the file, I get text with malformed non-ascii(czech) characters.
I am sure about the encoding of the file, as I converted the file to UTF-8 using iconv and when I wget/curl the file from bucket via the public URL and open it locally with anything, I can see the proper text.

How can I change the encoding, so when visiting URL via browser, I get shown the properly encoded text?

I tried changing Content-Encoding and Content-Language metadata without any effect.

Here are the headers when accessing the file via curl -v:

```
< x-guploader-uploadid: ABPtcPrh7TjXUhK7Itn1LHdEbNjAimXC9Nz3RR859S7IPtQrmm_TgetF6nrukga0eD5AQmmfaSA
< x-goog-generation: 1700571912281181
< x-goog-metageneration: 2
< x-goog-stored-content-encoding: utf-8
< x-goog-stored-content-length: 3777
< content-encoding: utf-8
< content-language: en
< x-goog-hash: crc32c=KGwFQw==
< x-goog-hash: md5=Fy4SQl6bi36t14gAhzFYUA==
< x-goog-storage-class: STANDARD
< accept-ranges: bytes
< content-length: 3777
< server: UploadServer
< date: Wed, 22 Nov 2023 00:41:12 GMT
< expires: Wed, 22 Nov 2023 01:41:12 GMT
< cache-control: public, max-age=3600
< last-modified: Tue, 21 Nov 2023 13:05:12 GMT
< etag: "172e12425e9b8b7eadd7880087315850"
< content-type: text/plain
< age: 63
```

Comment: What about Content-Type?

Comment: Added the headers from the curl: content-type: text/plain
Changed it in metadata to "text/plain; charset=UTF-8" but nothing changes

Comment: Google Cloud Storage does not modify your data. That means either you uploaded it wrong or are reading it wrong or there was a transformation. Your post does not show either. Use the CLI `curl` command to upload a file. Then download it using `curl`. Binary compare the bytes - they will be identical. Cloud Storage does not care when your encoding is. Only string-based clients care.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes, when I download using curl or wget, I get the good content. But when I open the .txt directly in browser via it's public URL, then I see bad encoding. I think it might do with bad HTTP headers sent along the response.

Comment: Use a different browser to test. Browsers cache, so the old headers might be a factor.

Answer (score 0):

The character encoding needs to be specified in HTTP header `Content-Type` like this: `text/plain; charset=utf-8`. The browser caches the headers, so it's needed to clear the browser cache in order for a change to take effect.